# Setting a class scope variable before calling a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that creates a d3 chart. It creates the chart in a `div` element based on its `id`, so I'm setting the `id` of the `div` during the initiation of the component and then calling a private function that creates the chart:

HTML:

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="header">Progress Status</div>
    <div id="{{chartId}}" class="gauge-chart-container"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
public ngOnInit(){
    this.chartId = 'chart-'+uuid();
    this.createGaugeChart(this.chartId);
}
```

The problem here is the function `createGaugeChart` runs before the div elements gets the `id` assigned, so when I add a `timeout` function it works:

```
public ngOnInit(){
    this.chartId = 'chart-'+uuid();
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.createGaugeChart(this.chartId);    
    },1000);
}
```

I'd rather not add a `timeout` of course, so is there a way I can wait on the HTML to render with the scope variables before calling any functions? Or maybe I'm calling the `createGaugeChart` function in the wrong location?

Comment: try running your code in ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.

I think you are probably after ngAfterViewInit()